# jQuery DataTables editing the row in jquery dataTable and save to the database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I am using jQuery dataTables, ajax, and web services to display my data from the SQL database. I am successful in doing this, however now I need a way to be able to update only one column of the record in the database from the datatable.

What I want: if I click on the edit button, the will be a modal pop and then I input a value in the pop, that value should be added to the already existing value in the database. This is because entries should accumulate on a daily interval when new entries are made. my issue is that I have managed to write the web method in the web service and it looks fine, but I can't update the field i want, please can you help as I don't have much knowledge with jQuery dataTables and ajax (how to get the id of the record I want to update and finally able to update in the client side using jQuery ajax)

This is what I have tried:

Clientside jQuery and ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        insertkpi();
        submitinit();

        displayKPI();
        updateprogress(Id);
    });
```

Displaying in the DataTable

```
 function displayKPI() {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'MyService.asmx/getKPI',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatable').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'Name' },
                            {
                                'data': '', 'render': function () {
                                    return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-target='#iniativemodal' data-toggle='modal'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>Initiative</i></a>";
                                }

                            },
                            { 'data': 'Initiative' },
                            {
                                'data': 'perfomance',
                                'render': function (perfomance) {
                                    return perfomance + "%";
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                'data': 'progress'
                                //'render': function (progress) {
                                //    return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-target='#progressmodal' data-toggle='modal'><i class='fa fa-pencil'>Progress</i></a>";
                               // }
                            },
                            { 'data': 'BaseTarget' },
                            {
                                'data': 'streachTarget'

                            },
                            { 'data': 'Period' },
                            {
                                'data': 'Id' ,
                                'render': function (Id, type, full, meta) {

                                    return '<a href="#" onclick="updateprogress(' + Id + ')" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>';
                                }
                            },
                        ]                
                    });
                }

            }
        );
    }
```

The function to update the database value taking the ID from the DataTable:

```
 function updateprogress(Id) {

       // var url = "MyService.asmx/getProgress?Id=" + Id+"";
       // var url = "MyService.asmx/updateprogres";
        $("#progrdata").load("MyService.asmx/updateprogres?Id=" + Id + "", function () {
            $("#progressmodal").modal("show");

            $("#progrebtn").click(function () {

                var progress = $('#pgtxt').val();
                var cid = Id.val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'MyService.asmx/updateprogres',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: '{Id: ' +Id + ', progress: "' + progress + '" }',
                    success: function () {

                        $('#progressmodal').modal('hide');
                    },
                });
            });
        })
    }
```

HTML markup:

```
 <div class="modal" id="progressmodal" data-keyboad="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Input Progress</h4>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="progrdata">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="pnamelb">Cumulative Progress</label>
                    <label id="prglbl" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id ="pinelb">Enter progress</label>
                    <label id="finalpglbl"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pgtxt" />
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn-primary" id="progrebtn">Save</button>
                <button class="btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void updateprogres(int Id,int progress)
    {
        string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE KPIs SET progress=@progress WHERE [Id] =@Id",conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@progress", progress);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add an `primary key` id column in datatable and hide it from the front end.

Comment: but i think i added it look here, {
                                'data': 'Id' ,
                                'render': function (Id, type, full, meta) {

                                    return '<a href="#" onclick="updateprogress(' + Id + ')" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>';
                                }

Comment: you like to update the whole table after update occurs? or only like to update the cell?

Comment: HI @MonkeyDLuffy, yes i want to update only the cell

Answer (score 0):

In success method of your ajax post. find the index of the td you like to update and set the progress to it. like ;

```
   $("#progrebtn").closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)").text(progress);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQaWeg

Comment: i have tried this just now but without success, i tried to debug and i saw that my web services is working just fine, but the issue is with the Url,

Comment: i have seen that im getting this error when i try to pass my parameters through the url in my webservices, how can go about it.   Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/updateprogres'.; this the url im using for testing the webservice http://localhost:49589/MyService.asmx/updateprogres?Id=60&progress=150

Answer (score 0):

So regarding my issue i have managed to solve it now, my error was that i was missing another parameter, that is the one i wanted to update. check the JS function now

```
 function updateprogress(Id) {

        // var url = "MyService.asmx/getProgress?Id=" + Id+"";

        var urll = "MyService.asmx/updateprogres?Id=" + Id + "&progress=" + $('#pgtxt').val() + "";

        $("#progrdata").load(urll, function () {
            $("#progressmodal").modal("show");

            $("#progrebtn").click(function () {

                var progress = $('#pgtxt').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                   url: urll,
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: '{Id: ' +Id + ', progress: "' + progress + '" }',
                    success: function () {
                        $("#progrebtn").closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)").text(400);
                        $('#progressmodal').modal('hide');
                    },

                });


            });
        })




    }
```